# RoundCube Send but dont receive

Tags: email, dovecot, roundcube

I just finished installing my Mail server following this tutorial : [here](http://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-an-email-server-on-centos7/)

And installed Roundcube following this tutorial : [here](http://howtoforge.com/running-roundcube-0.7.1-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.10#-installing-roundcube-)

So For now, I m able to send email but can't receive, so I need some help please.

I m using Centos 7, for further information just let me know.

Comment: Did you see there are two related questions to the right of this screen? BTW You are also not giving enough information. Those tutorials will probably say *Enter your X here* but we don't know what your X's are.

Comment: theses post aren't resolved, Just tell me which information you need and I will give you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's pointing, and I found the probléme.

I don't know how I overwritten the SSL files, so I generated it back and it work.